# azure - keep receiving 404 for a cognitive service I just signed up?

Tags: azure, http-status-code-404, azure-cognitive-services

This is super werid.

So I just created my resource group and signed up for a cognitive service.

pretty sure i have the right key and the right resource url.

yet I kept receiving "404 resource not" found for every api call i made to it.

Anyone ever ran into a problem similiar to this? And what do you think what might be the problem here? Will super appreicate any suggestions & recommendtions on how to resolve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it.. `imageSearchEndPoint` in

```
const client = new ImageSearchClient(cognitiveServiceCredentials, {
  endpoint: imageSearchEndPoint,
});
```

(of the @azure/cognitiveservices-imagesearch) should just be the full domain name and not the full api url

i.e. `https://meow.cognitiveservices.azure.com/` and not `https://meow.cognitiveservices.azure.com/bing/v7.0`.